# Format the date right into each table date JavaScript/html

Tags: javascript, html, date

so i have tried many things but i stuck at the point...

I want to format the date the jquery.datepicker has (right in the picture) transfers the same format to the  in HTML..

When I click the button to add the data in the table, the format is as you can see (left) in the pic.

```
    var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
    cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1), // Date
    date = document.getElementById("date").value,
```

more code.... but not important

Thank you guys!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the locale :

```js
  const formatted = date.toLocaleString('fr-FR') // or 'de-DE'
```

Then insert `formatted` in your table